# Why to_date function while parsing string column is giving null values for some records in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

[image]

Is there any difference in parsing of strings to date from the to_date function and the unix_timestamp and from_unixtime. Can anyone please explain.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `h` (`MM/dd/yy hh:mm aa`) rather than `H` (`MM/dd/yy HH:mm aa`) because your hour is a "clock-hour-of-am-pm", not a "hour-of-day". See the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html) for correct usage of datetime pattern strings.

You might also want to use a pattern that works with Spark 3.0, e.g.

```
M/d/yy h:mm a
```

so that you don't need to set the timestamp parser to legacy mode. Only one letter is needed for `M`, `d` and `h` because according to the docs, the number of letters...

> represents the maximum count of letters this type of datetime pattern can be used

while for `a`...

> Pattern letter count must be 1.

`from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())` returns a timestamp, while `to_date` returns a date. There is also a function `to_timestamp` which is essentially the same as `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())`.